# Inserting the value of my radio's into the database

Tags: php, html

I can insert the values of the radio's in the database but it only works if I have selected the radio 'vrouw' and if select 'man' it does not insert into the database.

Php function:

```
if (isset($_POST['submitForm'])) {

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbname = "schoolopdrachten";
    $dbusername = "root";
    $dbpassword = "";

    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbusername,$dbpassword);

    $stmt = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO javascript (naam, gender, land, provincie, suboptionman, suboptionvrouw) VALUES (:naam, :gender, :land, :provincie, :achternaam, :suboptievrouw)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':naam', $_POST['inputName']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':gender', $_POST['keuzegender']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':land', $_POST['select1']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':provincie', $_POST['select2']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':achternaam', $_POST['keuzeMan']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':suboptievrouw', $_POST['keuzeVrouw']);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Html:

```
<div class="container">

    <form method="post" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
        <fieldset>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="inputName">Naam</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="inputName" name="inputName" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control  input-md formFunction">
                    <p id="errorNaam" class="help-block formError"></p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Radio Keuze -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Geslacht</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label for="radioMan">
                            <input class="formFunction" type="radio" name="keuzegender" id="radioMan" value="man">
                            Man
                        </label>
                        <label for="radioVrouw">
                            <input class="formFunction" type="radio" name="keuzegender" id="radioVrouw" value="vrouw">
                            Vrouw
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <p id="errorRadioGroup1" class="help-block formError"></p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Keuze als man is gekozen -->
            <div id="keuzeMan" class="form-group hidden">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="optionMan">Achternaam</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input id="optionMan" name="keuzeMan" type="text" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md formFunction">
                    <p id="errorKeuzeMan" class="help-block formError"></p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Keuze als vrouw is gekozen -->
            <div id="keuzeVrouw" class="form-group hidden">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Leeftijd</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="optionVrouw1">
                        <input class="formFunction" type="radio" name="keuzeVrouw" id="optionVrouw1" value="Jonger dan 50">
                        Jonger dan 50
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline" for="optionVrouw2">
                        <input class="formFunction" type="radio" name="keuzeVrouw" id="optionVrouw2" value="Ouder dan 50">
                        Ouder dan 50
                    </label>
                    <p id="errorKeuzeVrouw" class="help-block formError"></p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Select Land -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectLand">Land</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="selectLand" name="select1" class="form-control  formFunction">
                        <option value="empty">--Kies Land--</option>
                        <option value="nederland">Nederland</option>
                        <option value="belgie">België</option>
                    </select>
                    <p id="errorSelectLand" class="help-block formError"></p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Select Provincie -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="selectProvincie">Provincie</label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select id="selectProvincie" name="select2" class="form-control formFunction">
                        <option value="empty">--Kies provincie--</option>
                        <option value="overijssel">Overijssel</option>
                        <option value="noordHolland">Noord-Holland</option>
                    </select>
                    <p id="errorSelectProvincie" class="help-block formError"></p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label" ></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input class="formFunction" type="checkbox" name="checkboxes" id="checkBox" value="checkBox">
                            Check het formulier & enable de verstuur button
                        </label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Button -->
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <button id="submitForm" name="submitForm" class="btn btn-success" disabled="disabled">Verstuur</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>
```

Database:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do in your processing page is check if the radio buttons are set first, then if they are, get the value.

Like this...

```
if( isset($_POST['keuzegender']) ) {
    $radio_value = $_POST['keuzegender'];
}
```

Other than that, your code looks correct.

Comment: for some weird reason it worked when I changed 'man' to Male... anyways thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score -1):

Radio buttons (and checkboxes) only send values if they are selected. They will not appear in the POST variables otherwise.

Comment: Yes, but when I select Man in the first radio options then it does not send anything to the Databaes, but if I select Vrouw which is in the same radio group as man it does send the whole thing to the database.. so for some reason it doesn't when 'man' is selected